# Naming of the output with an unprotected open drain or open collector on the silkscreen

Tags: transistors, output, open-drain, silkscreen

An issue has arisen regarding the pin **labeling** on the **silkscreen**. These pins are user-defined, so I want to clearly indicate that the output is transistor **open-drain**. As you may understand, it's a rather critical consideration.

Printing the entire datasheet on the board is not feasible. І need a concise and elegant solution.

Is there any established solution to this issue?

Comment: What do plc manufacturer's do on their open-collector outputs?

Comment: Who is the audience of your board? The symbols that are most intuitive to hobbyists vs analog EEs vs automation experts may differ.

Comment: just write (OD) or (open drain) if you have the room?

Comment: I believe my audience consists of "Arduino fan boys". When I observe how they use shields... I want to help them a bit. But I also want to know how the professionals do it.